# Which of these is more appropriate for learning C#: Visual Studio Express Web or Desktop?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, ide, visual-studio-express

I downloaded Visual Studio Express Web without even knowing there were 2 other versions (windows desktop and windows). I checked on stackoverflow and saw that the "windows desktop" version was probably better for learning C#. But what about Visual Studio Express Web? Would that be an equally good IDE to learn C# on?

Comment: Which is more applicable would clearly depend on what your goals are - do you want to produce Windows desktop applications or web applications? The IDE is the same, and the language is the same. What targets do you intend to develop for? (You can do both - just download both versions of the IDE.) Neither of the IDEs affects your ability to learn C#. The language remains the same regardless of the platform you choose to target.

Comment: To work with VS for Web you will also have to deal with: Setting up a Web Server, using HTML and ASP and CSS and some javascript/ tpescript and then some. So it will imply a lot of other things to get you busy and possibly confused..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you want to create simple console and Windoze Desktop apps (not Modern UI apps). In that case, **you want to use Visual Studio Express for Windows Desktop**.

Here is a short explanation of what each edition is for:

- **VS Express for Windows Desktop:** This is for creating desktop apps and console apps.
- **VS Express for Windows:** This one is for creating Modern UI apps, the ones that run full screen in Windows 8.
- **VS Express for Web:** This one is for creating web apps using .NET technologies such as ASP.NET MVC.

---

**Other Options**

Microsoft also has a new version if VS called **Visual Studio Community**. VS Community is basically VS Professional, but free. [According to the VS website](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs), the acceptable usage for individual developers are as follows:

> **Q: Who can use Visual Studio Community?**
>
> A: Here’s how individual developers can use Visual Studio Community:
>
> - Any individual developer can use Visual Studio Community to create their own free or paid apps.

---

**Would that be an equally good IDE to learn C# on?**

VS Express for Web would probably not be your best choice, mainly because it isn't quite as simple to create an app, run it and see results (which is what you want if you are learning).

VS Express for Windows gives you a straightforward way to create apps that you can run and see immediate results.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was really struggling to understand the differences! I will definitely start out with the windows desktop version and then I will decide later on if the web version is right for me.